# How to fetch only a subset of to-many relationships in Core Data and NSPredicate

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

This one is driving me nuts...

I have a model involving Events (each Event having a to-many relationship with RecordEntries) like so:

```
Event <---recordEntries--->> RecordEntry
```

What I want to do is to fetch an event and all associated recordEntries matching a specific ageGroup, gender and provinces (filtering out the recordEntries that don't match). To be clear, I need the Event object but I don't need all the recordEntries - I'm only interested in a subset of all the recordEntries in the Event.

So I tried doing this:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<Event>(entityName: "Event")
request.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["recordEntries"]

request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(%K, $r, $r.ageGroup == %i AND $r.gender == %@ AND $r.province IN %@).@count > 0", #keyPath(Event.recordEntries), ageGroupCode, userGender, ["CA", userProvince])
```

... and I end up getting all the records instead (and not the ones matching ageGroupCode, userGender and ["CA", userProvinces].

I also tried the following:

```
let recordAgePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY recordEntries.ageGroup == %i", ageGroupCode)
let recordGenderPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY recordEntries.gender == %@", userGender)
let recordProvincePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY recordEntries.province IN %@", ["CA", userProvince])

request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
  recordAgePredicate, recordGenderPredicate, recordProvincePredicate
]
```

... and this also returned all the records for the Event (including those I didn't want).

What am I missing here?!?

Comment: `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY (recordEntries.ageGroup == %i AND recordEntries.gender == %@ AND recordEntries.province IN %@)" ageGroupCode, the rest)` instead?

Comment: If you mean like so: `let recordsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY (recordEntries.ageGroup == %i AND recordEntries.gender == %@ AND recordEntries.province IN %@)", ageGroupCode, userGender, ["CA", userProvince])`, this fails (unable to parse the format string...).

Comment: If you use only this predicate let recordAgePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordEntries.ageGroup == %i", ageGroupCode), is it only fetching the records with ageGroup equal to ageGroupCode?

Comment: @user1000 the predicate you suggested resulted in a crash with "to-many key not allowed here"...

Comment: Ok if you apply only single predicate then what is the result: let recordAgePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY recordEntries.ageGroup == %i", ageGroupCode) , its from your code

Comment: @user1000 trying with only the recordAgePredicate still returns records outside of the targeted ageGroupCode (it returns all records for the entry, actually)

Comment: Are you sure name of properties in predicate are correct?please check,

Comment: The relevant properties are: 1) in RecordEntry: `@NSManaged public var ageGroup: Int16` and 2) in Event: `@NSManaged public var recordEntries: NSSet?`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152644/discussion-between-user1000-and-etienne-beaule).

Comment: @EtienneBeaule Since you are fetching Events, the predicate will have no effect on the contents of the `recordEntries` relationship.  If you want to filter the recordEntries relationship to the smaller set you are interested in, either apply the predicate to the `relatedEntities` set, or do a separate fetch for `RecordEntry` objects that are related to the relevant Event(s) and meet your other criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Credit for this answer goes to @user1000 who pointed me in the right direction (and provided several code snippets to try)...

Turns out that @pbasdf is right - when doing an fetch on Event, predicates on its recordEntries relationship have no effect.

What @user1000 suggested instead was to add the following following method to the Event class:

```
func recordsFilteredFor(ageGroup: Int, province: [String], gender: String) -> Set<RecordEntry>{
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "ageGroup == %i AND province IN %@ AND gender == %@", ageGroup, province, gender)
    let result = recordEntries?.filtered(using: pred)
    return result as! Set<RecordEntry>
}
```

With this in place, I can loop through the events and access only the records I want by looking into `event.recordsFilteredFor(...)` instead of `event.recordEntries`.

I am unclear yet what kind of impact this has on the performance. With this solution, I still end up fetching more than I need and then filtering this content afterwards but I do not have that many records to deal with.

I left the `request.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["recordEntries"]` in there, thinking that I was better off eager-loading all the relationships than to fetch them again in the recordsFilteredFor method. I still have to double-check if this has any benefits or not. Some initial testing suggests that I still end up with a fault being fired in the recordsFilteredFor method (which would make the eager-loading quite a pointless thing to do).

Until I find something better, looks like this will be my solution...